# App closes after posting 'č','š' and 'ž'

Tags: android

I have a problem posting words that contain characters like 'č','š' and 'ž'. The characters are all in the android keyboard. The app chrashes after I call startActivity(Jsoup_result). And also textview doesn't display this characters. It just displays �. At first it wouldn't even detect them and would just leave a blank space(with the UTF-8 parameter it returns the � character).

At first I thougt that the problem was just with the textview. When I input this characters the app just closes (it doesn't say that the app has stoped working). There are also no errors.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String url = "http://www.ap-ljubljana.si/vozni_red2/VR2.php";
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("VSTOP_IME", vhod));
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IZSTOP_IME", izhod));

    try {
        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        post.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        html_response = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), UTF-8);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return null;
}
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        Intent Jsoup_result = new Intent(getActivity(), HtmlCode.class);
        Jsoup_result.putExtra("html", html_response);
        startActivity(Jsoup_result);
    }
```

}

And here is the code from the activity that displays the results parsed by Jsoup

```
public class HtmlCode extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String value = intent.getStringExtra("html");
    setContentView(R.layout.htmlkoda);
    TextView tv_html = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_html);


    Document document = Jsoup.parse(value);
    Elements tr = document.select("select[name=VSTOP_ID]");
    Elements options = tr.select("select > option");
    value = "";

    for(Element element : options)
    {
        value += element.text() + "\n";
    }

    tv_html.setText(value);

}
```

}

**Logcat**

```
07-10 07:44:21.059    1110-1110/com.example.blaz.pager D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier﹕ KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
in android.widget.EditText{b3dd0c78 VFED..CL .F...... 12,190-468,249 #7f090004 app:id/ff_izstop}
0: sent at 305638000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=305638, downTime=305546, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
07-10 07:45:11.629    1110-1110/com.example.blaz.pager W/ViewRootImpl﹕ Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_C, scanCode=46, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=2, eventTime=356228, downTime=355674, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
07-10 07:45:11.629    1110-1110/com.example.blaz.pager W/ViewRootImpl﹕ Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_C, scanCode=46, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=3, eventTime=356337, downTime=355674, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
07-10 07:45:11.819    1110-1110/com.example.blaz.pager W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-10 07:45:11.879    1110-1110/com.example.blaz.pager W/ViewRootImpl﹕ Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_C, scanCode=46, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=4, eventTime=356388, downTime=355674, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
07-10 07:45:11.899    1110-1110/com.example.blaz.pager W/ViewRootImpl﹕ Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_C, scanCode=46, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=5, eventTime=356440, downTime=355674, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
07-10 07:45:11.899    1110-1110/com.example.blaz.pager W/ViewRootImpl﹕ Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_C, scanCode=46, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=6, eventTime=356610, downTime=355674, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
07-10 07:45:12.149    1110-1110/com.example.blaz.pager D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 164K, 6% free 3920K/4164K, paused 51ms, total 59ms
07-10 07:45:17.289    1110-1110/com.example.blaz.pager W/ViewRootImpl﹕ Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_Z, scanCode=44, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=2, eventTime=361978, downTime=361423, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
07-10 07:45:17.419    1110-1110/com.example.blaz.pager W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-10 07:45:17.459    1110-1110/com.example.blaz.pager W/ViewRootImpl﹕ Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_Z, scanCode=44, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=3, eventTime=362029, downTime=361423, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
07-10 07:45:17.469    1110-1110/com.example.blaz.pager W/ViewRootImpl﹕ Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_Z, scanCode=44, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=4, eventTime=362080, downTime=361423, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
07-10 07:45:17.479    1110-1110/com.example.blaz.pager W/ViewRootImpl﹕ Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_Z, scanCode=44, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=5, eventTime=362187, downTime=361423, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
07-10 07:45:23.049    1110-1124/com.example.blaz.pager D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 281K, 9% free 4127K/4492K, paused 54ms, total 55ms
07-10 07:45:23.769    1110-1124/com.example.blaz.pager D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 381K, 15% free 4034K/4692K, paused 70ms, total 71ms
07-10 07:45:23.769    1110-1124/com.example.blaz.pager I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 4.265MB for 262160-byte allocation
07-10 07:45:23.839    1110-1124/com.example.blaz.pager D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 128K, 16% free 4162K/4952K, paused 60ms, total 60ms
07-10 07:45:24.099    1110-1124/com.example.blaz.pager D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 36K, 16% free 4162K/4952K, paused 56ms, total 56ms
07-10 07:45:24.099    1110-1124/com.example.blaz.pager I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 4.640MB for 524304-byte allocation
07-10 07:45:24.169    1110-1124/com.example.blaz.pager D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 256K, 20% free 4418K/5468K, paused 47ms, total 47ms
07-10 07:45:24.509    1110-1124/com.example.blaz.pager D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 61K, 20% free 4418K/5468K, paused 52ms, total 52ms
07-10 07:45:24.509    1110-1124/com.example.blaz.pager I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 5.390MB for 1048592-byte allocation
07-10 07:45:24.599    1110-1124/com.example.blaz.pager D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 512K, 25% free 4930K/6496K, paused 48ms, total 48ms
07-10 07:45:26.249    1110-1110/com.example.blaz.pager W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

String vhod was defined as "Ljubljana" and izhod as "Čatež"

Comment: I'm glad your title was fixed, apparently posting � in the title was not a good idea :P however, I can't really tell what the error is, I've never seen anything like it before.

Comment: Yeah. Seems like most of the people mised my question because of that delay-

Comment: Not a good idea to put html_result in an extra for an intent and only show it in a new activity as during 'transport' changes can be introduced. Better: display right away in a TextView of the same activity. Print also to logcat. At the moment you use a json parser on value. That is not the way to test if characters are ok. Just display 'value' as it comes in.

Comment: If you look in the source of VR1.php you see `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">` So that could be valid for the response too. What did you try other than `response.getEntity(), UTF-8`?

Comment: I don't really know what is that supposed to mean. Is it something to do with the charset? I printed it out to logcat and it returned : "Ljubljana Iški most" but still the wrong charater for 'č' (Ljubljana Jakèeva). Insted of 'è' it's supposed to be 'č'

Comment: If the word 'charset' is in it than yes it has something to do with a char set. ;-).

Comment: Your log does not include anything directly related to a crash.

Comment: I copied the whole logcat. Like I wrote in the question. The app didn't technicly crash. There was no pop-up warning that the app stoped working.

Comment: Indeed I was just going to comment on that. Moreover: `App closes after inputing..` then it looks that before anything is send there is already a crash. Quite confusing.

Comment: If it stopped working and disappeared than that is technically a crash. What else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
html_response = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), UTF-8);
```

That does not compile. You ment:

```
html_response = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
```

But as the website delivers

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
```

you better use

```
html_response = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

I just displayed html_response in onPostExecute in a textView. And for me it looks ok.

**UPDATE**

After better realizing that something with windows-1250 had to be done i tried

```
html_response = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "windows-1250");
```

And.... Bingo! The characters are now the same as when posting with a browser.

Comment: Still no luck. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cfsf6hiwlm9ezn7/Capture.PNG)
At least now the app doesn't close. The first line in the screen capture (bottom textview) is determent in .xml and is there just to test if it could display these characters

Comment: Well that looks all very fine for me. Not a single �. Problem solved. Great! To test if you could display the characters you only had to do as i suggested. Nothing else. I do not understand why you name xml and that list on the screenshot you did not mention before.

Comment: But it still doesn't display them. There shouldn't be blank spaces or è character. Insted there should be č,š and ž. I already knew that it displayed blank spaces without UTF-8 parameter. I wrote it in the question. "At first it wouldn't even detect them and would just leave a blank space(with the UTF-8 parameter it returns the � character)."

Comment: but entityutils does not read the meta, so unless the encoding is also in the headers, it won't work.

Comment: That's very true indeed. So you give it a helping hand. If the caracters are not like the default charset on your phone (is it a phone or an Emulator?) and also not utf-8 then try other charsets. You now know that you receive windows-1250. "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250"

Comment: You cannot suppose us to see where the characters are wrong and where are spaces where they don't have to be. So post a little sentence from the response here three times: as it should be, as it is with spaces and so, as it is with �. Then we know where to look for.

Comment: Gr@#$### ... You have here `String url = "http://www.ap-ljubljana.si/vozni_red2/VR1.php";` But you have to post that to VR2.php as I already told you in another thread. #$%@%@% that took me time again.

Comment: Sorry. No need to be upset. It was a mistake. I have VR2.php in my program. I just copied it from the other question. Again sorry i ment to change it but forgot.